# How to use regex lookahead with big conditions?

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I want to detect things that start with @ and have a double bracket. @[uuid][displayValue]. I have the following regex for that.

```
@\[([^\][]*)]\[([^\][]*)]
```

I want to pair lookahead((?=) with it but doing that does not work.

```
(?=@\[([^\][]*)]\[([^\][]*)])
```

It does not return any match. Lookahead is to keep delimiter in javascript split function.

Consider the following example:

```
const text = 'I want to thank @[handle1][displayValue1], @[handle2][displayValue2] for their contribution'.
```

When I use `text.split(/(?=@\[([^\][]*)]\[([^\][]*)])/g)` with the regex, I am looking for following output

```
['I want to thank ','@[handle1][displayValue1]',', ','@[handle2][displayValue2],'for their contribution']
```

Comment: Can you show how you are using the regex in the string split and an example of what result you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

run the sniipet, and you get the matches with start indexes

```js
for( let a of 'I want to thank @[handle1][displayValue1], @[handle2][displayValue2] for their contribution'.matchAll(/@\[(.*?)\]\[(.*?)\]/g)){console.log(a)}
```

[image]

---

if uuid/displayValue might contain @[][] like words, you will need to code more logic, probably with a finite state machine